# DaggerMock library -how does it override module?

Tags: android, dagger-2

The [DaggerMock library](https://github.com/fabioCollini/DaggerMock), is used to override dagger modules with fake implementation.  Lets take a look at one robolectric topic that is confusing me:

```
 @RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class) 
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class MainActivityTest { 

    @Rule public final DaggerMockRule<MyComponent> mockitoRule = new DaggerMockRule<>(MyComponent.class, new MyModule())
            .set(new DaggerMockRule.ComponentSetter<MyComponent>() { 
                @Override public void setComponent(MyComponent component) { 
                    ((App) RuntimeEnvironment.application).setComponent(component); 
                } 
            }); 

    @Mock RestService restService;

    @Mock MyPrinter myPrinter;

    @Test
    public void testCreateActivity() { 
        when(restService.doSomething()).thenReturn("abc");

        Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class); 

        verify(myPrinter).print("ABC");
    } 
}
```

So i want to know, with this Rule what exactly is happening ? I can see that RestService was being provided by MyModule but is now being replaced with a mock. But in the examples i don't see a @Inject anywhere so i'm confused how the module was even used in the first place to provide any dependencies ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the author of DaggerMock, thanks for trying it!

The implementation is a bit complicated, the rule create a dynamic subclass of the module (using mockito) and override the provides methods. The rule scans the test fields so it return a field when the module has a method that returns the same type.

The final result is very similar to Mockito InjectMocks annotation. You can take a look at the implementation on github, the core class that override the module is this: https://github.com/fabioCollini/DaggerMock/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/it/cosenonjaviste/daggermock/MockOverrider.java

I release this lib just a week ago, any feedback is welcome!

Comment: So if i understand correctly, it mocks all the fields in the module i passed in,right? All provided fields from that module will be mocked?

Comment: No, it overrides just the module methods with a correspondent field in the test. So if you have no fields in the test no methods are overridden.

Comment: @FabioCollini can you please explain that a little more maybe with example "if you have no fields in the test no methods are overridden." ?